# how to copy a array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, for-loop, copy

I try to take only positive numbers from the array and display them in the second array. I copy one array to another but at the output I get only  0.
I’m a beginner in C#, so this is probably an easy thing to do

```
int[] array = { 12, 23, -22, -765, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 351, -999, -87 };
        int[] positive = new int[array.Length];
        int positiveCounter = 0;
        int[] source = new int[7];
        Array.Copy(positive, source, 7);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > 0)
            {
                positive[positiveCounter] = array[i];
                positiveCounter++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Positive numbers are: ");
        foreach (var item in positive)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Comment: "I copy one array to another but at the output I get only 0." - that's not what the code you posted does. You have a size mismatch between the original and the positives. You likely cannot or don't want to depend on a specific number of positives; you should take what's there no more or less.

Answer (score 1):

You can query initial `array` with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...
int[] array = ...

int[] positive = array.Where(item => item > 0).ToArray();
```

To show `positive` array in one go you can try `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", positive));
```

You can solve the problem with a help of loops (no Linq solution):

```
int[] array = ...

int positiveCounter = 0;

foreach (int item in array)
  if (item > 0)
    positiveCounter += 1;

int[] positive = new int[positiveCounter];

int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
  if (array[i] > 0)
    positive[index++] = array[i];
```

please note, that `Array.Copy` copies consequent items which is *not guaranteed*.

Answer (score 0):

As your request it will take all the positive number from 1st array and store in second array

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList array =new ArrayList{ 12, 23, -22, -765, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 351, -999, -87 };
        ArrayList array2 = new ArrayList { };
        foreach(int item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            if (item > 0)
            {
                array2.Add(item);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        foreach (int item in array2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```